# How to write case expression while pivoting the data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

```
CREATE TABLE details_1 (
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_details_1_e_id PRIMARY KEY ( e_id )
);

insert into details_1 values(11,'A');


CREATE TABLE ques_ans (
    ques_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ques_id  NUMBER(10),
    ref_ans_id   NUMBER(10),
    ref_ans_value VARCHAR2(100),
    e_id         NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_ques_ans PRIMARY KEY ( ques_ans_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ques_ans FOREIGN KEY ( e_id )
        REFERENCES details_1 ( e_id ),
        constraint fk_ques_and_ques_id foreign key(ref_ques_id)
        references ques_ref (ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ans values(1,3,1,11,null);
insert into ques_ans values(2,2,2,11,null);
insert into ques_ans values(3,4,1,11,null);
insert into ques_ans values(4,23,1,11,11);

CREATE TABLE ques_ref (
    ques_id     NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(50),
    code_label  VARCHAR2(100),
    constraint pk_ques_ref primary key(ques_id)
);

insert into ques_ref values(3,'changes_exist','Any known changes');
insert into ques_ref values(2,'E_Clubbed','E_id clubbed with other');
insert into ques_ref values(4,'E_impacted','E impacted by other');
insert into ques_ref values(23,'E_Clubbed_with_other','E clubbed with other E');

CREATE TABLE ans_ref (
    ref_ans_id  NUMBER(10),
    code        VARCHAR2(10),
    code_value  VARCHAR2(30)
);

insert into ans_ref values(1,'R_Yes','Yes');
insert into ans_ref values(2,'R_No','No');

commit;

My Attempt :

select  d.e_id,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 3 then ar.code_value end) changes_exist,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 2 then ar.code_value end) E_Clubbed,
        max(case qa.ref_ques_id when 4 then ar.code_value end) E_impacted,
--need to write case expression here
  from      details_1 d
        join
            ques_ans qa
          on d.e_id = qa.e_id
        join ans_ref ar
          on ar.ref_ans_id = qa.ref_ans_id
  group by d.e_id
```

I got stuck in the below requirement:

I need to check if `ref_ques_id` of `ques_ans` table is 23 then it should display `ref_ans_value` from the same table i.e `ques_ans`

For example:
In the table `ques_ans` for `ques_ans_id` 4 `ref_ques_id` is 23 then in this case it will display `ref_ans_value` i.e 11 in the column `ref_ans_value`

How can I write case expressions while pivoting the data?  I am wondering if we can do it using case expression or is there any other way to achieve this?

Expected Output:

```
+------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
| E_ID | CHANGES_EXIST | E_CLUBBED | E_IMPACTED | E_CLUBBED_WITH_E |
+------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|   11 | Yes           | No        | Yes        |               11 |
+------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with further aggregations.

```
CASE
    WHEN MAX(ques_ans.ref_ques_id) = '23' THEN MAX(COALESCE(ques_ans.ref_ans_value, 0))
    ELSE -4
END
```

There are two problems you will need to sort out:

## 1

You artificially aggregated things in the `SELECT` clause to prevent technical problems, but you might need to change this, depending on how your actual data looks alike (not the one shown in the question, but in reality). If you have answers with different references, then you might want to change your database structure to better reflect reality.

## 2

You did not tell us what should happen when the value of `ques_id` is **NOT** 23, so I added an ad-hoc value in the `ELSE`. You will need to change it to the one you actually need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround but when I am implementing the same logic I am getting null value. And I found that ```ref_ans_value``` column is having ```varchar2``` datatype. I just now checked that datatype is ```varchar2``` instead of ```number``` . Any suggestion? Why getting null value

Comment: I have edited the original question by changing the datatype. Now I am getting null values only

Comment: @Vicky I have edited my answer, but if you created a SQL fiddle, that would really help me fix your issue.

Comment: Below is the fiddle link where I am getting null values

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=900f434d4fd09935ef6f61eb30531a26

Comment: @Vicky you will need to compare with `'23'` then instead of `23`. Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00810c7a9a11fe1322e11640a4f85b05

Comment: ```ref_ans_value``` is having varchar datatype

Comment: @Vicky I think you did not check the Fiddle I have sent. I have edited my answer to show that the field we are speaking about is no longer `null` if we apply the fix I have suggested in my earlier comment.